# Algolia initial search parameters instantsearch.js

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an index where I am trying to pass initial values for the query in algolia. I am using the instantsearch.js and right now it just loads everything from my index. How can I pass initial values to the index on page load?

For example `Select * from index where Category='Careers'` (passing careers as a value on the load)

I've searched the documentation for this and cant figure it out.

Also, I need to pass multiple values, so something like:

`select * from index where Category = 'Careers' or 'Skills' or 'Interests'` (with or statements)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using a refinementList widget: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist. On the 'category' attribute of your data.

If so, you can do this:

```
var preselectedCategories = ['Careers', 'Skills'];

var search = instantsearch(applicationID, apiKey, {
  ...other parameters,
  searchParameters: {
    disjunctiveFacetsRefinements: {
      category: preselectedCategories
    }
  }
})
```

You will also need to do this in the refinementList instantiation:

```
var refinementList = instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
  transformData: {
    item: function(item) {
      if (preselectedCategories.indexOf(item.name) !== -1) {
        item.cssClasses.label += ' pre-selected';
      }

      return item;
    }
  }
});
```

Then all the preselected categories items will have the "pre-selected" css
class by default.

Then you can use css and this class name to do:

```
.pre-selected {
  display: none;
}
```

Let me know

Comment: I tried this, but it seems the array doesn't do an "OR" Statement.

Comment: Also, I just tried doing "disjunctiveFacetsRefinements". This works, however it just checks the checkboxes in the widgets as opposed to removing all of them but the two values.

Comment: sorry forgot to put your username @vvo

Comment: We are also thinking to provide it in a simpler way, its not obvious at all how to do this for now: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/853

Comment: confused as to what the template does. Are you saying to just create some css that hides it?

Comment: Yes, basically you can take the default template and add the preselected class conditionnaly (and so hide the preselected values). Default item template is: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/blob/498577e4c3785c373c273913833ead5a90c7fbf7/src/widgets/refinement-list/defaultTemplates.js#L3